# Can't get flexbox elements to line up horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't figure out why I can't get these three flexbox elements to line up horizontally across the screen. The left and center elements work fine side by side, and the center div is properly centered on the screen. The right side column sits properly to the right, but for some reason it sits towards the bottom, below where the bottom of the center element would be.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 90%;
    font-size: .75rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.left-column {
    left: 2px;
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    font-family: Poppins;
    color: #D7DBDE;
    margin-top: 11%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px;
}

.center-column {
    padding-top: 15px;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.right-column {
    right: 2px;
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    font-family: Poppins;
    color: #D7DBDE;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px;

}
```

Comment: Do not combine `display: flex;` and `float`. Instead, use the proper flex properties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use all those `float` properties while using `flex`. If you want to push the `left` and `right` columns to left and right sides, you can achieve this by simply using :

```js
//To push the right and left columns to right and left sides
.container {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

//To make even space between the columns 
.container {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

//To pull all columns to left
.container {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

//To push all columns to right
.container {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

**Styles for the columns**

```js
.container {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: .75rem;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px; 
    /* Apply Different flex properties */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container > div{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>


<div class="container">
    <div class="left-column">Left</div>
    <div class="center-column">Center</div>
    <div class="right-column">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The left column has `margin-top: 11%;` Please remove this and not use `float` with `flex`

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;   
    font-size: .75rem;
    display: flex;    
}
.container div{
  padding: 15px 5px 0 5px;
}
.left-column,.right-column {  
  font-family: Poppins;
    color: #D7DBDE;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="left-column">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      <div class="center-column">
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
    <div class="right-column">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
```